# Carregar imagem do pacote da aplicação utilizando File

Tags: java, arquivo

Bom dia,

Como faço pra carregar uma imagem que está dentro de um pacote do projeto usando a classe File do Java?

Exemplo, tenho uma imagem dentro da pasta "img" do meu projeto e quero carregar essa imagem pra criar um Objeto File:

```
File file = new File("img/logo.png");
```

Mas ele não encontra o arquivo de jeito nenhum, já coloquei o caminho de várias formas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) ou a versão getResource que retorna a URL para o arquivo que faz parte do seu classpath.